# Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: permission denied error accessing node.socket over shared volume mount in docker

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, docker

I am putting together an application in docker (compose) that has 2 services:

- Cardano Node
- Web Application

Both services/containers shares the node-ipc via volume mount, when I try `query tip` via the web application, I am getting permission denied. This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3.5"

services:

  cardano-node:
    container_name: cardano-node
    image: inputoutput/cardano-node:${CARDANO_NODE_VERSION}
    networks: [ my-app-network ]
    environment:
      - NETWORK=${NETWORK}
      - CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
    volumes:
      - node-db:/data/db
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"

  web-service:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: web-service
    tty: true
    networks: [ my-app-network ]
    volumes:
      - ../application:/home/web/application
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    environment:
      - CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
    ports: [ "8080:80" ]

volumes:
  node-db:
  node-ipc:

networks:
  my-app-network:
```

After building the above, I shelled into the `web-service` container and ran the following:

```
./bin/cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 2
```

Getting this error:

> cardano-cli: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: permission denied (Permission denied)

I checked the `/ipc/node.socket` exists via the shared volume mount and I can see it:

```
web_service@0f78c2f4136e:~/application$ ls -lah /ipc
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 00:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Oct 19 00:13 ..
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Oct 19 00:13 node.socket
```

Any idea why I can't seem to share the `node.socket` via volume mount?

Comment: According to the docs, this should be possible: https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-node


 Mount a volume for establishing cross-container communication via node.socket

`docker run -e NETWORK=mainnet -v node-ipc:/ipc inputoutput/cardano-node`
`docker run -e NETWORK=mainnet -v node-ipc:/ipc inputoutput/some-node-client`

Answer (score 5):

The cardano-node inside the docker run as root, and created node.socket as root:

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Oct 19 00:13 node.socket
```

HOW TO:

METHOD 1: You can try to change the owner directly, but next time restart the docker compose, it will back to root again.

```
sudo chown $USER node.socket
```

METHOD 2: Try to run cardano-node as your user id.
add `-u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER})` in docker run command or `user: <user id>:<user group>` in docker compose

METHOD 3: Remap User ID.
Here is the config guide
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap